# Accessing dictionaries in Django templates

Tags: html, django, dictionary, django-templates

## views.py:

```
return render(request,'images.html',temp)
```

## Temp:

```
{'cluster1': ['temp/vinoth/cluster1/demo-pic94.jpg', 'temp/vinoth/cluster1/id1.jpg'], 'cluster2': ['temp/vinoth/cluster2/demo-pic94.jpg', 'temp/vinoth/cluster2/demo-pic99.jpg', 'temp/vinoth/cluster2/id2.jpg', ['temp/vinoth/cluster2/demo-pic94.jpg', 'temp/vinoth/cluster2/demo-pic99.jpg', 'temp/vinoth/cluster2/id2.jpg']], 'cluster3': ['temp/vinoth/cluster3/demo-pic96.jpg', 'temp/vinoth/cluster3/id3.jpg'], 'cluster4': ['temp/vinoth/cluster4/demo-pic99.jpg', 'temp/vinoth/cluster4/id4.jpg'], 'cluster5': ['temp/vinoth/cluster5/demo-pic99.jpg', 'temp/vinoth/cluster5/id5.jpg'], 'cluster6': ['temp/vinoth/cluster6/id6.jpg', 'temp/vinoth/cluster6/triplet loss.jpg'], 'cluster7': ['temp/vinoth/cluster7/id7.jpg', 'temp/vinoth/cluster7/triplet loss.jpg'], 'cluster8': ['temp/vinoth/cluster8/id8.jpg', 'temp/vinoth/cluster8/triplet loss.jpg'], 'cluster9': ['temp/vinoth/cluster9/id9.jpg', 'temp/vinoth/cluster9/triplet loss.jpg']}
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

The Values are array of images

## image.html:

```
<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col">
            <ul class="list-group">
                {% for key,value in temp.items %}
                    <h1>{{ key }}</h1>
                {% endfor %}        
             </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

But nothing gets printed What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I want as key and below key all the images listed :ex cluster1 as heading below it all the images inside cluster1

Comment: You're passing {'cluster1': ..., 'cluster2': ...} as context to your template, so there's no such variable as `temp` defined. The context variables in your template are `cluster1`, `cluster2`, ...

Comment: You probably want `render(request, 'images.html', {'temp': temp})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `temp` variable you are "sending" to template is called `context` and you will be able to access to its items by its key values:

```
<div class="row mt-4">
<div class="col">
        <ul class="list-group">
            {% for value in cluster1 %}
                <h1>{{ value }}</h1>
            {% endfor %}        
         </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

In other words, each value of your `temp` variable will be accesible in the template directly with its `key` name. So, you will have in your template a `cluster1`, `cluster2`, ... `cluster9` vars in your template.

If you want to wrap all your vars in only one, you need to modify your context (`temp`) as follow:

`temp = {
   'data': {
      'cluster1': ...,
      ....
   }
}`

In the template:

`{% for cluster in data %}
  {% for img in cluster %}
    ...
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}`